# catching weekends and weekdays from given date vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I am trying to catch weekends and separate them from weekdays however I am getting stuck, for some reason I am returned a time of 12:00AM instead of a weekday name?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim MyFirstDate As String = "5/14/2020" ' This would be my textbox normally speaking....
        Dim elements() As String = MyFirstDate.Split(New Char() {"/"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)


        Dim MyDayOfWeek As String = ((elements(2)) & "," & (elements(0)) & "," & (elements(1)))

        Dim dateValue As DateTime = New DateTime(MyDayOfWeek)
        MsgBox(dateValue.ToString("dddd"))
        If dateValue.ToString("dddd") = "Saturday" Or dateValue.ToString("dddd") = "Sunday" Then
            MsgBox("weekend skiped")
        Else
            MsgBox("weekday")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: `dim myFirstDate = DateTime.Parse("5/14/2020", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) if myFirstDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday then ... `. `TryParse()` if the date comes from User input.

Comment: Ooh (feeling embarrassed) that's a lot shorter than what I tried

Comment: Just take a glance at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netcore-3.1 There are tons of things you can do with dates.